# REPLACE and SUBSTRING in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to mask a certain string such that only its last 4 characters are visible and rest are masked.

I have tried the below code in SQL server.

```
select REPLACE(trans_no,substring(trans_no,1,len(trans_no)-4),'*') from uvi_generalledgerwf where trans_no = '11043770'
```

Actual Result - *3770

Whereas, my expected outcome should be ****3770

This transaction number's length may vary but the last 4 digits from right should always be visible.

Comment: What is your actual database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to give you an answer here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mask characters in string SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213938/mask-characters-in-string-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest method is:

```
select concat(replicate('*', len(trans_no) - 4), right(trans_no, 4))
from uvi_generalledgerwf
where trans_no = '11043770';
```

The key idea here is that `replicate()` returns `NULL` when the value is negative -- so there is no problem.  `concat()` ignores `NULL` values so short strings are handled correctly.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad0113813df0588256e494c76e0caf94) is a db<>fiddle showing how it works for various string lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for SQL Server, which however should work across pretty much any database:

```
SELECT
    trans_no,
    SUBSTRING('**********', 1, LEN(trans_no) - 4) +
        SUBSTRING(trans_no, LEN(trans_no) - 3, 4) AS trans_no_masked
FROM uvi_generalledgerwf
WHERE
   trans_no = '11043770';
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to simply concatenate the correct number of `*` from a static string along with the last for digits from the `trans_no`.  To support `trans_no` of a higher length, use a larger string literal with enough `*` in it.

Comment: Thanks Tim for such a quick response. Unfortunately, my Report engine SQL is unable to reconize ||.

Comment: Yes, probably because you are using SQL Server (though you forgot to tell us this).  Reload your page.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works when the trans_no is not of a fixed length.

```
DECLARE @trans_no CHAR ( 255 );

SET @trans_no = '0808683370';
SELECT
    CONCAT(
REPLICATE
    ( '*', LEN( @trans_no ) - 4 ),
    SUBSTRING( @trans_no, CASE WHEN   LEN( @trans_no ) > 3 THEN  LEN( @trans_no ) - 3 ELSE  1  END, LEN(@trans_no) ) 
    )
```

You can test it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=974fe247ef4a9ea2ded5e84abb74d0ff

Then in your real application, you can use it as follows:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
    REPLICATE ( '*', LEN ( trans_no ) - 4 ),
    SUBSTRING( trans_no, CASE WHEN LEN ( trans_no ) > 3 THEN LEN ( trans_no ) - 3 ELSE 1 END, LEN ( trans_no ) ) 
    ) as masked_trx_no
FROM
    uvi_generalledgerwf 
WHERE
    trans_no = '11043770'
```